# how to configure php email in blue host to use mail() function?

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-ini, bluehost

I have migrated my php app to BlueHost hosting server, but notifications are not working anymore, I have created the file php.ini inside my root php application, and set

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

But emails are not being sent, in the last server it was working fine.

Thank you and grettings!

Comment: Check your local mail server's log files; that will tell you what has happened to messages that it accepted. I recommend avoiding using the `mail()` function altogether. It's better to use SMTP to localhost if you have a mail server, as it's faster and easier to debug, especially if you use a library like PHPMailer that you tagged the question with.

Answer (score 3):

The [SMTP ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) are used on Windows only and is really only meant for development testing purposes.

You should use an SMTP library, such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), to relay the messages to an external server.

If you have access to install software on the server an alternative would be to set up a mail server (like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)) to relay messages to an outside server. The advantage of doing it this way is that you do not block script execution, but is much more advanced and difficult to set up.

Comment: thanks, I will check the postfix solution to configure my domain email